# Semantic UI Modal showing PDF in Miniature Size

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using a modal to show a pdf when a hyperlink is clicked.

My modal div and the hyperlink is defined as below

```
<div id='pdf_modal' class="ui sixteen wide column fullscreen modal">
    <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8119/App/Inv.pdf"></iframe>
</div>
<a id='visualize'>Open PDF</a>
```

And i have this Javascript to load the modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#visualize').click(function()
        {
            $('#pdf_modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have also created a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4woemsjt/1/

For some reason, the resulting modal window shows the PDF document in a tiny left corner. Image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHf7P.jpg

[image]

I want to be able to see it covering almost the whole area of the modal.

What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to give that iframe some width and height

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/4woemsjt/2/

You can use percentage of the viewport screen height with the vh unit:

```
#pdf_modal iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:80vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to apply a style to the iframe using semantic ui classes? Also, the traditional buttons to print/save the PDF are missing. How can we solve that?